# Passing a return value from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have two react components:
Component1 renders a Map with MapboxGl.
Component2 renders a button that when clicked, makes an API call and fetches Geojson data and stores it into a variable.

Problem:
Component1 needs the Geojson data to draw a route on the map.
How can I pass the the data from component2 to component1?
I tried with exporting the variable from component2 and importing it in component1, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from one component to another ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181503/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-reactjs)

Comment: See also [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out but it doesn't seem to work for me, since the variable i want to pass, doesn't have the value yet, since it gets the value only after a function is called. So i'ts not a static value.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I recommend using either [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Here's the gist with context (it's a bit simpler imho than Redux).  The example is based off [this article](https://medium.com/@danfyfe/using-react-context-with-functional-components-153cbd9ba214).

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

const GeoJSONContext = createContext({})  // this will be the geojson data.

const GeoJSONProvider = GeoJSONContext.Provider

const ButtonContainer = (props) => {
  const { setGeoJSON } = useContext(GeoJSONContext)

  return <Button onClick={() => setGeoJSON(await fetchGeoJSON())}> 
             Get Data 
         </Button>
}

const MapContainer = (props) => {
  const { geoJSON } = useContext(GeoJSONContext)

  return <Map data={geoJSON} />
}

const App = (props) => {
   const [geoJSON, setGeoJSON] = useState([])

   return (<GeoJSONProvider value={{ geoJSON, setGeoJSON }}>
             <MapContainer />
             <ButtonContainer />
           </GeoJSONProvider>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the **Button** component as prop and call it when data is received. This means the container component hosting the map and the button component needs to keep state for the returned data.  The state is then passed as property to the **Map** component

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 components that you are having are independent to each other then what you probably need is a state container such as [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). Wrap the 2 components in a new component and move all the data that needs to be shared in the store. Otherwise go by Wakeel's answer - [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).